# it's "means" a singular of plural

Tags: grammar, nouns

I was confused about this question:
Eating garlic has long been regarded as a **means** of warding off malaise, and scientific research has shown that it does have some therapeutic values.

why **means** should be used here, instead of mean?

Comment: because **means** is a different word than the plural of mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*[Means](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/means)* here refers to a method of doing something.

Comment: No mean feat it was to so counter your own mien as to meanly suggest that that *means* means something other than what [that *mean* means](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/205327)! Take care lest someone should mean themself to the Powers That Be upon your mean ways.

Comment: The explanation provided in the reply still leaves one issue unanswered. Why is "means" probably the only noun ending with "s" that allows an indefinite article "a" before it?

Comment: It’s not. There are many such nouns. Firstly, there are many that just happen to end in an s (bus, kiss, abyss, lass, truss, etc.); secondly, there are quite a few nouns that are morphologically plural, but which are nonetheless treated as singulars (means, news, data [sometimes], etc.; as well as diseases like measles, chicken pox, etc.; activities like billiards, sports, etc.; and branches of science like math[ematic]s, linguistics, etc.). Why such words are treated as singular is an entirely different kettle of fish, which we don’t need to fry here.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Not one of your examples in the second list can take an *a* determiner when used as a noun. I have heard things like *a checkers* and *a dice*, though.

Comment: @PhilSweet True, _means_ is the only one of those that can act as a count noun. There’s also _a shambles_ and I’m sure at least a fair few others.