# Is there a word to describe this linguistic error?

Tags: single-word-requests, errors

Francis Galton originally used the term "regression to mediocrity" to refer to the phenomenon that children of very tall parents were on average less tall. More generally, the heights of children over multiple generations would regress toward the mean, or average, height of the population.

Today, "regression" is used to describe a particular statistical model in which data is distributed around a mean.

Galton writes,

> The mean regression ... is easily ascertained

intending to mean something like

> It is easy to ascertain the mean amount of regression

but a careless reader could instead understand

> It is easy to ascertain this thing called a "mean regression"

of which the contemporary meaning of regression is a natural extension. A phenomenon ("regression") was described with a statistical model, but the name of the phenomenon came to be used to refer to the model itself.

I'm struggling to think of a less esoteric example, although I feel like there should be more of these. Is there a name for this kind of error? Are there more familiar examples of it, ideally ones that don't rely on somewhat archaic language?

Comment: How about "pun"?

Comment: I don't see how this is a pun. For one thing, it's a mistake and not a play on words.

Comment: To me a mean regression could either be "a reversion to the average" or it could be a regression that takes pleasure in hurting others-  that's a pun in my book.(A pun doesn't have to be on purpose.)  However it's not clear to me that that's even what you're asking about because you go on to talk about "the name of the phenomenon being used to refer to the model itself" which kind of sounds like a *metonym*  Could you please refine and clarify your question?

Comment: Malapropism, in a way.

Comment: OP, does this fit what you are thinking of? "Amadan, what's wrong?" "Doctor, you have to help me, I kicked the bucket!" "You look alive to me..." "What? No, I mean the bucket in front of your office, it was full of sand, I think I broke my toe..." Possibly [duplicate](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/125405/what-do-you-call-it-when-someone-misunderstands-a-homonym)

Comment: What we have here is a *failure to communicate*. Kidding aside, I'm not sure we can find fault in the author's phrasing or the readers' interpretation. Both are legitimate. But for the sake of helping others find answers, maybe the question can be rephrased as "*Is there a name for choosing the wrong interpretation of an ambiguous text which has two or more legitimate interpretations (whose meanings are both valid, but different from one another)?*". Ideally an ambiguity or confusion which arises from breaking a packaged idioms down into its components and reading the sentence differently.

Comment: @Jim Metonymy was what i had in mind. _Unintentional_ metonymy. Also, I see what you mean about a pun, but I didn't say (or mean to imply) anything about hurting others. The second meaning, that of a statistical model, exists because of this apparent misreading, so it can't be a pun.

Comment: I don't believe that this was a mistake ***or*** a pun. It was a different use of the word, but it indeed had the real meaning of regression. As you accumulate more and more data, the observed average regresses to the true mean. And a *regression* is a means to estimate the true behavior of some phenomenon, which behavior follows the *"curve of regression"*.

Comment: I'm not sure that the former concept existed in Galton's day. That's what I'm asking about: confusing and conflating "regression to the mean across generations" with "fitting a regression to estimate the amount of regression to the mean across generations."

Comment: No, if anything was being conflated, it's *"regression to the mean across generations"* and *"regression to the mean through the avenue of collecting more data".* The phrase *"fitting a regression"* comes from the second of these concepts, and not the first.

Comment: That's not different from what I said, it's just a better way to say it. Again, the error of substituting #2 in place of #1 is what I'm asking about

Answer (score 2):

I think what you are asking is ***syntactic ambiguity*** (also called *amphiboly* or *amphibology*).

> Syntactic ambiguity is a situation where a sentence may be interpreted in more than one way due to ambiguous sentence structure.
>
> Syntactic ambiguity arises not from the range of meanings of single words, but from the relationship between the words and clauses of a sentence, and the sentence structure implied thereby. When a reader can reasonably interpret the same sentence as having more than one possible structure, the text meets the definition of syntactic ambiguity.

More specifically, it can be defined as *globally ambiguous*. It is mentioned as a form of syntactic ambiguity along with *locally ambiguous*.

> A globally ambiguous sentence is one that has at least two distinct interpretations. After one has read the entire sentence, the ambiguity is still present. Rereading the sentence does not resolve the ambiguity. Global ambiguities are often unnoticed because the reader tends to choose the meaning he or she understands to be more probable.

Wikipedia article lists some examples also. Two simple ones:

> - John saw the man on the mountain with a telescope.
>
>   *Who has the telescope? John, the man on the mountain, or the mountain?*
> - Flying planes can be dangerous.
>
>   *Either the act of flying planes is dangerous, or planes that are flying are dangerous.*

<sub><sup>Source: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntactic_ambiguity</sup></sub>